# Sandcastle - dead links, "access is denied" and other woes

Tags: javascript, sandcastle, chm

(Using the GUI builder)

Does anyone have any idea what this thing wants from the Html Help 2.x feature set?

It keeps throwing up "access is denied" errors in any non-local .chm file it generates, specifying the "ms-help://hx/hxruntime/hxlink.htc". Same error for a generated website. Let's not get into the fact that if I generate a .chm anywhere but my hard drive, all the links are dead, regardless of where the file is later moved.

**sigh**

What irritates me is that I *am* using a fresh download of Sandcastle, from Microsoft's site(May 2008). So it's not as though it's an old version. Am I just missing something massive here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure but you may be falling into the OSs security trap.

I have found that help files that are sourced outside the server are frequently blocked.  You need to unblock the file (in the case of CHMs) by right clicking it, selecting properties and clicking the Unblock button.

That sorted out the problem for me.  Good luck.